# Facebook Post Fields "to" and "message_tags"

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know the format of the arrays or objects that need to be passed to the "to" and "message_tags" fields that are outlined on this page of the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Answer (score 0):

The "to" field should look like this:

```
    "to": {
          "data": [
            {
              "name": "Abc Def", 
              "id": "##########"
            }
          ]
        }
```

The "message_tags" field looks like the following. Note that what I'm denoting as '#1#' is the offset from the beginning of your message text where the first character of the tag appears and '#2#' is the length of your tag.

```
"message_tags": {
      "#1#": [ 
        {
          "id": "##########", 
          "name": "Abc Def", 
          "type": "user", 
          "offset": #1#, 
          "length": #2#
        }
      ]
    }
```

I used the [Facebook Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) on an existing object to find the syntax.